# SQL Server add strings (of 0,1) logically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (lets call it AAA) in which each of my 4 channel_ids has its own dedicated `publish flag` column which is a char(4) consisting of 0s,1s

Here is an example

```
on_date                 rate_id type_id channel_id  publish_flag
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      1       1           1000
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      1       2           0100
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      1       4           0000
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      2       1           1000
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      2       2           0100
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      2       3           0001
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      2       4           0000
```

I want to group the results by

- on_date (in this example 2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98)
- rate_id (in this example 98)
- type_id (in this example 1 and 2)
- and instead of channel_id to have the "logical addition" of the publish flag columns

Example of the above transformation:

```
on_date                 rate_id type_id     publish_flag
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      1           1100    
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 98      2           1101
```

**So for first group:**

```
1000   +
0100   +
0000   =
--------
1100
```

**and for the second group:**

```
1000   +
0100   +
0001   +
0000   =
--------
1101
```

Is there a trick in which I can achieve the above in MS SQL Server 2008R2?

Thank you

Comment: I Improve the text format but still dont understand what you mean by logical addition.

Comment: What if you have a 0010 + 0011? Would it be 0101 or 0021?

Comment: A regular SUM would work with your example?

Comment: In binary `0010 + 0011 = 0101` unless you mean `OR` then `0010 or  0011 = 0011`

Comment: Ideally, change your database design. Storing *multiple* values in a single column (for a single row) is usually just a way of storing up future problems in maintaining and querying your data.

Comment: @PaulG sum dows not work for char colums

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanx for the formatting! I mean the OR

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever unfortunately I have "inherited" it and it cannot be changed at the moment :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i can tell, you need the highest bit for each position.
Try this:

```
SELECT 
  on_date,rate_id,type_id,
  MAX(substring(publish_flag, 1,1)) + MAX(substring(publish_flag, 2,1)) + 
  MAX(substring(publish_flag, 3,1)) + MAX(substring(publish_flag, 4,1)) as publish_flag
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY on_date,rate_id,type_id
```

Comment: What a brilliant and simple idea! I think it works like a charm!